# Comparing a string and number when using `drop if` syntax

Tags: stata

Here is my code snippet:

```
drop if mark=="." & spr_code==""
```

and Stata's response

```
type mismatch
```

The string is the `spr_code`

The issue is that I only want `drop` observations if BOTH the student mark is "missing" AND their `Spr_code` (which is alphanumeric) is also missing.

Can anyone help?  I've  already tried to `destring` the Spr_code and do this but no joy.

Comment: If  either `Spr_code` or `spr_code` (variant spellings; you may or may not mean the same variable; we can't tell)  is numeric, then it can't be string. Therefore you can't `destring` it and the test for missing would be (e.g.) `spr_code == .`. If this doesn't clarify, download `dataex` using `ssc inst dataex` and show us a reproducible example of your code.

Comment: Daer Nick, here is the data via dataex:* Example generated by -dataex-. To install: ssc install dataex
clear
input str18 spr_code float mark
"#3008029/2" 66
"#3505642/3" 60
"#3656497/4" 57
"#3822516/4" 56
"#3829774/3" 69
"#3830284/3" 68
"#3870111/4" 53
"#4023234/2" 54
"#4221966/2" 76
"#4476034/1" 44
"#4498593/2" 60
"#4547926/2" 71
"#4548264/2" 58
"#4552768/2" 66
"#4679253/1" 59
"#4922042/1" 65
"#5955416/1" 58
"#5963451/1" 52
"#6027601/1" 51
"#6034535/1" 52
end
label var spr_code "#SPR_Code" 
label var mark "Mark"

Comment: Please add  as aligned code in an edit to your post,

Comment: Sorry but I do not understand what "add as aligned code" means, but the problem is now fixed in that the code that worked was : drop if mark==. & spr_code==""

Comment: Dear Nick, my problem has now been fixed, it seems I was treating numeric variables as strings and vice versa, but I am not sure how that was the case as they were both coloured red in the browse screen.  Stata said that the numeric variables contained non-numeric characters, I assume these are "/" and '#" , and Stata would not let me encode them to numeric.  Anyway I am sure this is a novice error on my part.  And hope to get better with time  Thanks for your help, KL

Answer (score 0, accepted):

My guess is that `mark` is a numeric variable and in the snippet it is treated as a string.
In that case the code should be:

```
drop if mark==. & spr_code==""
```